# During checkout, button "continue" doesn't work

Tags: checkout, onepage-checkout, product-attribute, eav

I have a problem on the magento ecommerce that I am creating. When I procede to checkout in the "billing information" section, the button "continue" after I insert user personal data doesn't work. It also doesn't work if I try to procede with a registered user.

Here is the link to the test website:

http://shop.overland.org/mshop/magentoboh/index.php

In the system.log file the following error appears:

> 2014-07-30T09:47:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning:
>   include(Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream:
>   No such file or directory  in
>   /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 93
>
> 2014-07-30T09:47:26+00:00 ERR (3): Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='/app/code/local:/app/code/community:/app/code/core:/lib:.:/usr/local/php53/pear')
>   in
>   /lib/Varien/Autoload.php
>   on line 93

I tried researching a bit and as suggested by someone I already attempted replacing the Autoload.php file. The error persists though. The system requirements are met. I have magento 1.8.1.0. Anyone can help?

Thank you very much.

Edit 1: I uploaded a screen with the database result following Dave's comment.

[image: Database results screen]

Edit 2: I don't know if it's related to this problem but another error pops up in the error log.

> ERR (3): Notice: Undefined index: customer_group_id  in /app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Product/Collection.php on line 1778

Answer (score 3):

It's trying to include the model for an attribute type which doesn't exist. Thus the invalid **Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/.php** path in your error.

By the fact it's trying to include **.php** I'm going to presume that one of your attributes has no frontend_input set. To locate this login to your database and run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM eav_attribute WHERE frontend_input = '';
```

Once you've got the results you should be able to determine which attribute is invalid and also then work out what sort of frontend_input it should have. If you're uncertain text is a safe bet. Feel free to reply with the attribute and I'll guide you.

Comment: Hello Dave,

thank you for your answer. I initially wanted to give it a try alone but then I thought it might be better not to mess up stuff. I edited my initial post up above with the screenshot of the results my database gives. If you could kindly guide me through I would appreciate it a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Indii there are so many potential factors causing this error. It's near impossible to help you fix it without having full access to your site and it's code to conduct numerous different tests to identify the issue.

Comment: WOW. This really works. You saved my day man! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not the Autoload.php is the problem, the filepath `Mage/Eav/Model/Attrbut/Data/.php` looks invalid. There either is a filename missing before the .php ending or the / after Data is superflous. Probably wrongly configured in a config.xml (The include_path suggests in a community module)

The Autoload.php throws the error because it tries to access this invalide filepath to load a class.

p.s. lacking reputation to make this a comment it is an answer instead.